# Is there any way you can check after a while what the battery percentage was on linux at boot?

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, battery

Let's say I'm using my laptop for an hour and I see that the battery percentage is currently at 30%. I am interested in what was the battery percentage was when the laptop started.
Is the battery percentage logged somewhere when the system boots or is there a way to record it at boot and be able to check it some time later?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Linux records the battery charge at boot, but you could
do it yourself by
[Run a Script on Startup in Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup).

For measuring the battery charge you could use utilities such as
[Powertop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/powertop)
or
[UPower](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower).

You could then save the battery state at boot and compare it with
its current status.

Links :

- [Linux Laptop Display Battery Status And Thermal Temperature From Command Line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-laptop-battery-status-temperature/)
  (about upower)
- [Display backlight consumes too much battery power](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256093)
  (examples of using powertop)